# Properly using subprocess.PIPE in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use `subprocess.Popen` to construct a sequence to grab the duration of a video file. I've been searching for 3 days, and can't find any reason online as to why this code isn't working, but it keeps giving me a blank result:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

def main():
  the_file = "/Volumes/Footage/Acura/MDX/2001/Crash Test/01 Acura MDX Front Crash.mov"
  ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', the_file], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, )
  grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'Duration'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, )
  cut = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f', '4'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, )
  sed = subprocess.Popen(['sed', 's/,//'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, )

  duration = sed.communicate()
  print duration

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Why are you using grep, cut and sed to parse the output instead of using builtin Python functions?

Comment: [subprocess.PIPE](http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/)  is your enemy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

stderr needs to be redirected to stdout. Also, there's no need to call other tools like `cut/sed` etc. do your string manipulation in Python

```
import subprocess
....
the_file = "/Volumes/Footage/Acura/MDX/2001/Crash Test/01 Acura MDX Front Crash.mov"
ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', the_file], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout = subprocess.PIPE )
out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
if "Duration" in out:
    print out[out.index("Duration"):].split()[1]
```

If Python is not a must, you can use the shell directly.

```
the_file="/Volumes/Footage/Acura/MDX/2001/Crash Test/01 Acura MDX Front Crash.mov"
ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I had to redirect `stderr` as well.

Answer (score 25):

As others have pointed out, you need to pass the PIPE from one process to the next.
The stdout (PIPE) from one process becomes the stdin for the following task.

Something like this (starting from your example):

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

def main():
  the_file = "/Volumes/Footage/Acura/MDX/
              2001/Crash Test/01 Acura MDX Front Crash.mov"
  ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', the_file],
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'Duration'], 
                          stdin = ffmpeg.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  cut = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f', '4'],
                         stdin = grep.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  sed = subprocess.Popen(['sed', 's/,//'],
                         stdin = cut.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

  duration = sed.communicate()[0]
  print duration

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I'd consider this the correct answer, it answers exactly what OP asked and isn't instructing on how you could work around it.

Comment: There is a pipes module nowadays: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html?highlight=pipe#module-pipes

Answer (score 14):

Using `subprocess.PIPE` will not magically wire the correct pipes for you.

You must pass the output pipe of the first process as the value for the parameter `stdin` of the second process. [See the docs for an example](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Answer (score 4):

Python can't "build a whole pipeline" in this way -- it could delegate the task to the shell, or glue it up more directly using the `stdout` attributes of previous subprocess objects in the line, but there's really no reason for that in this specific case, since you can code it directly in Python pretty easily.  E.g.:

```
  ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', the_file],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  for line in ffmpeg.stdout:
    if 'Duration' not in line: continue
    fields = line.split()
    duration = fields[4].replace(',', '')
    break
```